# Game Engine for City Simulation Game for Python

Tags: open-source, python, game, game-development

## Software suggestion:

- I need a **game engine** which facilitates ***my requirements.***
- **City Simulation** means building a city from plain land. Or **City Building Game** which is same as **City Simulation!**

---

### Requirements:

**1. Free**
**2. Open-source**
**3. Easy to use**
**4. Compatible with Python**
**5. 3D support**

---

#### Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone answer my question?

Comment: This is the correct site for the questions you are asking, but for future info, you might want to be aware of our [games development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) sister-site. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panda3D is free, open-source, compatible with Python, and supports 3D rendering. Most of it is easy to use, but it does have optional advanced features and some concepts like collision detection have a steeper learning curve.

https://www.panda3d.org/